# What do negative numbers under TIME+ in htop mean?

Tags: time, process, top, htop

What do the red negative numbers I'm seeing displayed in htop mean?

[image: What do these mean?]

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just arithmetic overflow, and htop using a signed datatype where it should be unsigned. The column shows the accumulated CPU time for those processes.

You should not be worried.

(What is your uptime? Is it a VPS?)

Comment: EC2 instance. Uptime is 53 days, 23 hours.

Comment: Thing is, I have another instance that's been up 867 days, with a mysql process that's logged 389 hours, and never seen anything like this in htop.